# If column returns null results check another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySQL and I want to compare the 1st table1.columnA with the 2nd table2.columnB.  If the results are null, I want to compare the 1st table1.columnA with the 3rd table (table3.columnC).  What's the best way to write that in MySQL?

I tried the below but no luck

```
select table1.columnA,table2.columnB, table3.columnC
from  table1.columnA
left table2.columnB
on table1.columnA = table1.columnA
left table2.columnB
on table1.columnA = table3.columnC
where ifnull((table1.columnA = table2.columnB), table1.columnA = table3.columnC);
```

Comment: This is no valid SQL. `from table1.columnA` should read `from table1`. `left table2.columnB`should read `left join table2`. `on table1.columnA = table1.columnA` looks like a typo. And what do you want to select after all exactly? Please show some sample data and expected results to make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
where case when table2.columnB is null then table1.columnA = table3.columnC
           else table1.columnA = table2.columnB 
      end
```

Or:

```
where coalesce(table2.columnB, table3.columnC) = table1.columnA
```

P.S. there is no `left` , but `left join`.

Comment: The solution with `case` shouldn't work, since `case` returns a value, so it should be `table1.columnA = case ...`

Comment: @HoneyBadger: Well, yes, value – `true` or `false`, though your notation is better (because it is shorter).

Comment: @potashin I tried the coalesce, but it didn't return any results. I have to admit it, my actual code has more dynamics, but has the same outline. I tried the below but it didn't work

`select table1.columnA,table2.columnB, table3.columnC
from  table1.columnA
left table2.columnB
on table1.columnA = table1.columnA
left table2.columnB
on table1.columnA = table3.columnC
where coalesce(LEFT(table2.columnB,4) AND (LEFT(table2.columnX,4), 
(LEFT(table3.columnB,4) AND (LEFT(table3.columnX,4)) =
((table1.columA,4) AND LEFT(table1.columnX,4));`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL at least you have to check for null using `is null` or `is not null`. Also I assume by "Left" you mean "Left Join", it is important to include the  join part for the sake of the query though most people will understand what you mean.

You must also define what is being checked for null. Your current snippet is rather vague: it wants a null to pop out of the comparison and get flagged, but you would really have to check the value for null when it is individually parsed.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Coalesce should do the trick

```
SELECT COALESCE([tablea].[col1],[tableb].[col1],[tablec].[col1])
FROM [tablea]
LEFT JOIN [tableb] ON [tablea].[col1] = [tableb].[col1]
LEFT JOIN [tablec] ON [tablea].[col1] = [tablec].[col1]
```

This will return the first null value, or you could have a default value if none is found

```
COALESCE([tablea].[col1],[tableb].[col1],[tablec].[col1],'No value')
```